# Firebase Real Time Database,get data from key-value pair

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating my first android firebase test project, and facing a problem trying to get back the data. Here is how my data looks like in the console:

[image]

and my code to retrieve the age and name:

```
databaseReference.child("users").child(firebaseUserId).child("profile")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Name: " + users.getName() + "\n" +
                                "Gender: " + users.getGender(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

and the User(POJO) class looks like this:

```
public class Users {
String name, gender;

public Users() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
}
```

However, I am unable to do this, and the program crashes with this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type project.ibrapptly.com.kcpe_tests_and_quizzes.Users
```

How can I get my data back, or what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
databaseReference.child("users").child(firebaseUserId).child("profile")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Name: " + users.getName() + "\n" +
                            "Gender: " + users.getGender(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

into this:

```
databaseReference.child("users").child(firebaseUserId).child("profile")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Name: " + users.getName() + "\n" +
                            "Gender: " + users.getGender(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

You need to remove the for loop in this case. When you are looping you are retrieving the attributes `age` and `name` which are of type String.